# is There alternate of counter method in spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase?

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

i am migrating Spring boot version. in latest spring boot version 2.6.0 in spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase counter() method have been removed. i need increment operation. Before in couchbase 2.2.5.RELEAE in Bucket class have counter method. this method fetch data from couchbase and increment the updated value
Example :

```
public String getConId(final Long start) {String conId = null;final Bucket bucket = couchbaseTemplate.getCouchbaseBucket();final Long id = bucket.counter("RetDtcomConId", 1, start).content();conId = id.toString();return conId;}
```

But in new spring boot version 2.6.0 spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase use spring-data-couchbase 4.3.0
here in Bucket class counter methode removed.

```
public String getConId(final Long start) {
        String conId = null;
        final Bucket bucket = couchbaseTemplate.getCouchbaseClientFactory().getBucket();
        final Long id = bucket.counter("RetDtcomConId", 1, start).content();
        conId = id.toString();
        return conId;
    }
```

please suggest me how to increment couchbase value.

```
public String getConId(final Long start) {
        String conId = null;
        final Bucket bucket = couchbaseTemplate.getCouchbaseBucket();
        final Long id = bucket.counter("RetDtcomConId", 1, start).content();
        conId = id.toString();
        return conId;
    }
```

Expected result should : increment with 1
Example now in couchBase DB have value 4 the result should be 5 for RetDtcomConId

Comment: `Bucket` is a Couchbase class **not** a Spring Data class. That support was removed from Couchbase itself. See https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-java-sdk-3-0-counter/29806

Answer (score 0):

In SDK 3 the atomic counter methods live in the [BinaryCollection](https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client/com/couchbase/client/java/BinaryCollection.html) class, accessed by calling [collection.binary()](https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client/com/couchbase/client/java/Collection.html#binary())

(Thanks dnault)

Answer (score 0):

repository.getOperations().getCouchbaseClientFactory().getCluster().bucket("b").scope("s").collection("c").binary().increment("abc")

template.getCouchbaseClientFactory().getCluster().bucket("b").scope("s").collection("c").binary().increment("abc")